# maven rpm plugin does not copy config files at first place

Tags: java, maven, configuration-files, rpm, rpm-maven-plugin

I'm using maven rpm plugin for making an rpm installation file for my java web application. I copy class and config files into ubuntu tomcat7 and then start tomcat. I make rpm file and then using "alien" I convert it to .deb file.
The problem is that the files which are marked as configuration files are not copied at first place.

```
<mapping>
   <directory>/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes</directory>
   <configuration>noreplace</configuration>
   <filemode>777</filemode>
   <username>elaheh</username>
   <groupname>elaheh</groupname>
   <sources>
       <source>
          <location>target/project/WEB-INF/classes/config.properties</location>
       </source>
   </sources>
</mapping>
```

I set configuration "noreplace" here. I also tested configuration=true. But none of them worked.
I need something to copy configuration files first time but on update doesn't override them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your rpm, most likely reason is that config files are not getting packaged along with rpm. There is no reason why rpm will not deploy config files if they have been packaged.
If you find that files are not getting packaged then you should paste your pom to investigate the issue further.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked generated deb file and the config files are in it. There is a file named "conffiles" in Debian/conffiles. This file contains list of config files and it's content is correct.